# Should I specify the same quadratic features for training and testing in Vowpal Wabbit?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, vowpalwabbit

I run my VW model in test mode (using `-t` flag) with `-q SE SZ DR`, where `S, E, Z, D, R` are my namespaces. Then I bump into the the following warning in the diagnostic printout:

`WARNING: model file has set of {-q, --cubic, --interactions} settings stored, but they'll be OVERRIDEN by set of {-q, --cubic, --interactions} settings from command line.`

So the question is: when creating quadratic features, should I specify the same namespaces after `-q` flag when *testing* as were used for *training*?

At first, I decided that yes, I'd better do this because otherwise: (a) either quadratic features will not be created and they weights will be ignored in testing; (b) or they will be created but hashed to buckets different from those in training set. Both ways will deteriorate performance, that's what I thought. But the aforementioned warning makes me doubt. So how does VW work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the warning states, options that are already stored (persisted) in the model file, shouldn't be repeated (or changed) on the command-line.

In other words: if you trained with `-q XY ...` interactions, these interactions have already been stored in the model. They are initialized when you load the model at startup (with `-i model_file`), so there's no reason to (re)include them on the command line.

Not all command line options are model-persistent: for example, by default, the loss-function (`--loss_function ...`) is not stored in the model, so if you run a regression, you can change the loss-function with every test-run. A pretty useful feature.

You can always tell which options are persisted in the model by creating a "readable model" using `--readable_model file_name` and looking at its header (1st few lines).